# ñ character showed as �, when retrieving from mysql to php

Tags: php, html, mysql, mysqli, utf-8

I have a data in my mysql database's table which is `Biñan`. However, when I try to retrieve it using php, it showed as `Bi�an` in my dropdown list.

Here is my sample code:

```
<?php
   $query = "SELECT * from municipality";
   $res = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
   {
     echo "<option value='".$row['m_id']."'>".$row['m_name']."</option>";
   }
?>
```

But when I manually echo/insert the character `ñ` in php/mysql it displayed as is. I have also set the charset to `UTF-8`.

**PROBLEM SOLVED!:** I just have to replace the `ñ` with `Ã±` in my database's table. So it shows `ñ` in my website.

Comment: **NO!**  Two wrongs do not make a right!  Don't "replace the `ñ` with `Ã±`"!  See "black diamond" in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored for the likely cause(s) of such.  That should help you solve it completely, not one case at a time!

Answer (score 0):

add this in your head html file.

in a balise:

> meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"

Comment: I followed your instruction, but the output was still the same..

Answer (score 0):

Try to:

```
ALTER DATABASE <databasename> CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE municipality CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Answer (score 0):

otherwise it's in the database.
do this in your database.

> ALTER TABLE municipality COLLATE utf8_general_ci

```
or
```

> ALTER TABLE municipality CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8;